# Preprocess bad scans (partially blurred, shadowed and slightly skewed) for OCR

Tags: python, opencv, tesseract, image-preprocessing

I try to read documents from various sources with Python. Therefore I am using OpenCV and Tesseract. To optimize the Tesseract performance, I do some preprocessing, but sadly the documents also vary in quality a lot. My current issue are documents that are only partially blurry or shaded, due to bad scans.

I have no influence on the document quality and manual feature detection is not applicable, because the code should run over hundred thousands of documents in the end and even inside a document the quality can vary strongly.

[image: original bad image]

To get rid of the shadow, I found a technique with delating and blurring the image and dividing the original with the dilated version.

```
h, w = img.shape
kernel = np.ones((7, 7), np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
blurred_dilation = cv2.GaussianBlur(dilation, (13, 13), 0)
resized = cv2.resize(blurred_dilation, (w, h))
corrected = img / resized * 255
```

That works very well.

[image: corrected exposure]

But I still got that blur and optically it got worse to read.
I'd like to do a binarisation next, but then would be nothing valuable left from the blurred parts.

I found an [example of a deconvolution](http://amroamroamro.github.io/mexopencv/opencv/weiner_deconvolution_demo_gui.html) that works for motion blur, but I can only apply it to the whole image, which blurs the rest of the text, and I need to know the direction of the motion blur.
So, I hope to get some help on how to optimize this kind of image, so that tesseract can properly read it.

I know that there should be further optimizations besides sharpening the blurred text. Deskewing and getting rid of the fragments of another pages.
These I am not sure about the proper sequence how to perform these additional steps.

I can hardly find sources or tutorials for plain document optimization for OCR processes.
Often the procedures apply globally to the whole image or are for non OCR applications.

Comment: deskew: find peaks in FFT. very robust. http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textdeskew/index.php by the way: hough transform is a bad idea. inaccurate or expensive. also stochastic.

Answer (score 2):

Reminds me of this article I read a few years ago: https://medium.com/illuin/cleaning-up-dirty-scanned-documents-with-deep-learning-2e8e6de6cfa6

Contrary to the title, it contains a variety of classic computer vision algorithms for your inspiration.

- To **remove shadow**, I've personally had **median filtering** as described (removing a median-filtered background) work more effectively than what you show here.
- To **deskew**, I've experimented with **Hough transform** and got good results.

Intuitively, if you should know the font type and size in advance, that should help as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.filters as filters

# read the image
img = cv2.imread("input/ocr.png", 0)

# blur
blurred_dilation = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (91, 91), 0)

# divide gray by morphology image
division = cv2.divide(img, blurred_dilation, scale=255)

# sharpen using unsharp masking
sharp = filters.unsharp_mask(division, radius=11, amount=11, multichannel=False, preserve_range=False)
sharp = (255 * sharp).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(sharp, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# save results
cv2.imwrite('receipt_division_sharp.png', sharp)
cv2.imwrite('receipt_division_thresh.png', thresh)
```

[result,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQM2X.png)
[result with threshold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uQ7z.png)

method: unsharp_mask filter, Otsu's method (1979)

ref: [OpenCV: Contour detection of shadowed image before OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63884290/opencv-contour-detection-of-shadowed-image-before-ocr)
(2020 stack overflow)

If I were You, I'll try GAN. Though raw data is blurred and shadowed, You need clear data for tesseract. So You need to generate clear character from blurred raw data.